# How to cut Selected portion of the sound file using iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-audio

I am working in a app in which i need to cut the selected portion of a sound file. But I dont have any idea how to do that.
If any one can reply me with code then it would be better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean an editor ? showing waveform and ability to edit sound !?

Answer (score 2):

There is an audio engine ["FMOD Ex Programmer's API"](http://www.fmod.org/products/fmodex.html), available for [multi-platforms](http://www.fmod.org/fmod-downloads.html#FMODExProgrammersAPI), including iOS. It is free for non-commercial use.

You can also use Core Audio Units. Some references:

- [Audio Unit Hosting Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/AudioUnitHostingFundamentals/AudioUnitHostingFundamentals.html) from Apple
- [Audio Unit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) from Apple
- [iOS Audio Programming](http://izotope.fileburst.com/guides/iZotope_iOS_Audio_Programming_Guide.pdf) from [iZotope](http://www.izotope.com/) (also an audio processing library provider)